# Find string, select that row and all rows above it

Tags: vba, excel, select

I'm trying to select a range from the top of my worksheet (columns A:E) until the words "Grand Total" including the row that those words appear in. Then I want to copy that range and paste it in a different worksheet. The code I have for finding "Grand Total" so far is, but it's not working:

```
Sub QuickFind()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strFind As String
strFind = "Grand Total"
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Cols("A").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox strFind & " not found"
Else
    Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlDown)).Activate
End If
End Sub
```

I copied this from somewhere and it said `ActiveSheet.Rows(1)`.  It doesn't seem to like how I changed it to `ActiveSheet.Cols("A")`.

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Columns(1).Find(...)`. There is no `Cols` property in a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx).

Comment: Your code contradicts your title and narrative. You state you want to select from the top down to *Grand Total* but your code is written to select everything from *Grand Total* down.

Comment: Yeah. I meant to do from Grand Total up, not down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should you want to copy/paste the range in ACtive Sheet from row 1 to the row where "Grand Total" is found in column "A", included, then you could use this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub QuickFind()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strFind As String

    strFind = "Grand Total"

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng1 = .Range("A:A").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If rng1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox strFind & " not found"
        Else
            .Range("A:E").Resize(rng1.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("different worksheet").Range("A1") '<~~ change "different worksheet" with actual name of the worksheet you want to paste to
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

if you are interested in copying values only then substitute:

```
            .Range("A:E").Resize(rng1.Row).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("different worksheet").Range("A1") '<~~ change "different worksheet" with actual name of the worksheet you want to paste to
```

with:

```
            Worksheets("different worksheet").Range("A1").Resize(rng1.Row, 5).Value = .Range("A:E").Resize(rng1.Row).Value '<~~ change "different worksheet" with actual name of the worksheet you want to paste to
```

Answer (score 0):

This small change:

```
Sub QuickFind()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim strFind As String

    strFind = "Grand Total"
    Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If rng1 Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox strFind & " not found"
    Else
        Range(rng1, rng1.End(xlDown)).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

will select everything from "Grand Total" to something below it:

[image]

*Note:*

*It selects downward rather than upward.*

Comment: I think OP is asking for selecting a range from the top of his worksheet (columns A:E) until the words "Grand Total"

Answer (score 0):

Sub QuickFind()

Dim rng1 As Range

**Dim theRngWhereYouWantToPaste As Range**

**'Change the range below to where you want**

**Set theRngWhereYouWantToPaste = ActiveSheet.Columns("F:J")**

Dim strFind As String

strFind = "Grand Total"

Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.Columns("A").Find(strFind, , xlValues, xlWhole)

If rng1 Is Nothing Then

MsgBox strFind & " not found"

Else

**Range("A1:E" & rng1.Row).Copy Destination:=theRngWhereYouWantToPaste**

End If

End Sub